# Angular JS not loading view in browser

Tags: angularjs

I have written my first Angular JS but it is not loading in the browser. When I run the file, I get a blank screen. However when I do away with the script tag, the page renders.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
enter code here<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Angular Demo</title>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<h2>Welcome {{name}}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should check out your console log which let you know the details of the problem you have faced.

Comment: check whether `"lib/angular/angular.min.js` is correct. Seems like you omitted `"` at the end. So, it should be `"lib/angular/angular.min.js"`

Comment: As @JohnyStark said, add the missing " character and it works. That's one of the reasons you should use a smart text editor with syntax hilighting or a proper IDE to write html, javascript and other code - you would have spotted that immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it on a server to render angular content in browser. Otherwise, as you have faced, a blank page is displayed. Try using node.js for the same.